# Android studio: Error while installing apk

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

[image: this is the image of my problem]

When I launch my virtual device ,it launches but my app doesn't show in `AVD`.
I update all the plugins and platforms required..after some time android studio given this error as following : `Error while installing apk.`

Please, solve my problem why this is happening, I'm suffering from 2 days.:(

Comment: Try deleting your current avd and create a new one.

Comment: same problem occured in my android studio repeatedly. but I jst clean and rebuild the project and just run by emulator . it succesfully installed and launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried increasing the `adb` connection time out on the `AVD`?

To test this, first launch the `avd` and make sure it is turned on and running.  Then try to build your application and install the `.apk` onto the device.

Comment: it's showing session timeout error.. please share how to increase adb connectiom timeout?

Comment: If you are on Android Studio : File->Settings->Tools->Tasks->Connection Time out

Comment: it doesn't work for me, but you solve my problem indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your emulator up and running.

Also you can try running it on to your phone the process is simple,

1. Go to android `setting=>About=>Click on build varian 7 times to become developer.`

2.go to developer section and enable the debugging mode.

3.now if you are on window pc you have to download `google usb driver` and for MAC you can directly connect and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you should uninstall all the applications that were developed by you in the emulator. After uninstalling all the applications that were build by you in the emulator, then clean project, run it again.Let me know if this works out.